# Entity Framework - Self Tracking Objects - how to reset client side?

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I am using wcf with self tracking entity framework objects.

On the client side i have bound an entity to an edit form (which has multiple textboxes and comboboxes).

After the user hits Save, the entity is sent through wcf to the server wcf service which will attempt to save the entity.  If there is a failure (say a network failure), I need to reset the current entity back to original values.

How best can I do this client side? (I recognize with Self Tracking objects there is a property OriginalValues however that collection seems to have count=0) so not sure how to get the original values?

Thanks-